# Can Spider-Man change the color of his webbing?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

I was playing the new Marvel's *Spider-Man* game for PS4 and was looking at all his new suits and it came to mind, is it possible for Peter Parker to change the color of his webbing? For example, from white to red/black etc. In any cinematic universe, comic or movie.

Comment: Just add some food dye to the cartridge surely?

Comment: It depends. In some incarnations, the webbing is produced by his body as part of his powers - this is the case for the three Tobey Maguire Spider-Man films - so it probably wouldn't be possible to change. In others, the webbing is manufactured and shot using mechanical web slingers, so would likely be possible to change the colour - this is the case for the Andrew Garfield Amazing Spider-Man movies and the Spider-Man from the MCU.

Comment: I am sure Tony's spidey suit had that feature.. The only problem is that Thanos snapped it out of existence.

Comment: In all my life, never seen a different color webbing.

Comment: @OrangeDog from a technical perspective no, Spidroin is not water soluble and is unlikely to hold the food dyes. Fabric dyes are the way to go.

Answer (score 22):

In a word, yes. Peter slings red webs in [Peter Parker: The Spectacular Spider-Man 
 #305](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/69277/peter_parker_the_spectacular_spider-man_2017_305)

[image]

Black webs in [Spider Man Noir #001](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Spider-Man_Noir_Vol_1_1)

[image]

And he adds something to his normal web fluid to make them *extra sticky* in [Ultimate Spider Man #001](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Spider-Man), at which point they go a sort of sickly green colour.

[image]

Comment: I would just clarify that the 3 Spider-Man examples you gave are from 3 different Marvel universes. Main, Noir, and Ultimate.